# Python Tkinter to create a dialog just like VC++ DoModel()

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a dialog just like VC++ `dlg.DoModal()` did.
I have created a parent dialog for my main UI with a `'button_A'` on it.
After I click on the `'button_A'` on main UI, it will create a child dialog.

Now I have 2 dialog, parent and child. My problem is the child dialog will be covered by parent dialog if I click on parent dialog. Is there any way to make child dialog always on top event I click on parent dialog?

```
# python 2.7
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
from Tkinter import IntVar
from Tkinter import *

class MyGUI():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        ## Set the focus on dialog window (needed on Windows)
        master.focus_set()
        ## Make sure events only go to our dialog
        master.grab_set()

def start_test():
        handle = tk.Toplevel(root)
        my_login_dialog = MyGUI(handle)
        handle.wait_window(handle)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('')
root.geometry('1024x768')

ft1 = tkFont.Font(size = 10,weight = 'bold')     

tk.Button(root,text = 'Button_A',bg = 'white',height = 1,width = 8,font = ft1,
            command = start_test).place(x = 50,y = 10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: try `handle.transient(root)`  before `wait_window`

Comment: I think you can title your question better using _"Is there any way to make child dialog always on top event I click on parent dialog?"_ sentence. I for one have no idea what the title means.

Comment: The suggestion did works fine. Thanks for help. And sorry for confusing  people about the question not clear enough.